# Does basis of eigenspace mean the same as eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a 3x3 matrix, 2 eigenvalues (one with multiplicity 2) and now 2 eigenvectors, how do you find the basis for each eigenspace?

Answer (score 2):

There's two cases:

- if the matrix is diagonalizable hence the dimension of every eigenspace associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to the multiplicity $\lambda$ and in your given example there's a basis $(e_1)$ for the first eigenspace and a basis $(e_2,e_3)$ for the second eigenspace and the matrix is diagonal relative to the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$
- if the matrix isn't diagonalizable so  the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity $2$ has the dimension equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenspace can mean the span of the matrix's eigenvectors.

Comment: Awesome thanks, and is the eigenspace 3x2 if you only have 2 unique eigenvalues?

Comment: One can ask, "What is the eigenspace associated with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$?"  The answer to the question is the span of the eigenvectors that have $\lambda_1$ as an eigenvalue.  So the answer to your comment question depends on the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue.  An eigenvalue can have more than one eigenvector associated with it.

Comment: How does it get more than one? Is this a rare case like the squareroot of a number is +- or what are you getting at? So if a 3x3 matrix produces 2 unique eigenvalues, each with its own 3x1 eigenvector, then the eigenspace is 3x2?

Comment: An eigenvector for an eigenvalue lambda is an elements of the null space of $A - \lambda I$.  The null space of this matrix can have a dimension higher than 1.  It's not "unusual" to be in this situation.  If there are two eigenvalues and each has its own 3x1 eigenvector, then the eigenspace of the matrix is the span of two 3x1 vectors.  Note that it's incorrect to say that the eigenspace is 3x2.  The eigenspace of the matrix is a two dimensional vector space with a basis of eigenvectors.  (Note: I'm assuming that the eigenvectors of the two eigenvalues are independent.)

Comment: Thanks again. So how do you go from the eigenspace (the span of 2 vectors) to the basis of the eigenspace?

Comment: A basis for a vector space $V$ is a set of independent vectors that span the space $V$.  If you have independent eigenvectors, then you have a basis for your space.